# How to create SRV record using external-DNS?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-ingress

I am using external-dns and as ingress solution I am using Voyager. 
I am looking to create SRV records to my hosts that are running  on k8s cluster on aws.

Becasue of the services that I am running on my k8s cluster I am looking to create SVR records for the exposed ingress services in same way I am using for the hostname.

Anyone has any idea how to create srv records with external-dns?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide more detailed information I will post general information how to get DNS Records.

In order to create DNS records via External-DNS you have to create:

- DNS Zone
- Nginx Ingress Controller
- Service
- ServiceAccount
- ClusterRole
- ClusterRoleBinding
- Deployment
- Setup ExternalDNS

All detailed steps are provided [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/nginx-ingress.md#deploy-a-sample-application). Also much general information about required/supported stuff can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns).

Please note that if `ExternalDNS` is ignored in your setup you should check `--source ingress` flag in manifest.

If you will adjust manifest with your data and provide good annotations to nginx, you should be able to see DNS records for Ingress.

Comment: Hi PjoterS. As we know on this moment external-dns creates 2 types of records A and TXT for the same entry. TXT record is used for Registry Identifier and A, we all know what is for. The application I am working on needs a [SRV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record)  record type too.   I was wondering if external-dns supports any annotations ( kubernets or helm) that will enable the creation of SRV record.

Thank you for you answer.